# Force div to occupy the rest of space with css-grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Is there a way to force the grid container to extend to the end of the screen with `css-grid` (see snippet below, where I use `height: 80vh;` for a manual approach for visualization's sake)

EDIT: I could always know the height of the header and footer, and then use for example `grid-template-rows: calc(100vh - ...px);`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #f6eeee;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 200px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
}

.left {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: calc(100vh - 2*112px - 2*12px);
  /* 100px height + 10px padding + 2px border */
  /* 10px margin + 2px border */
  overflow: auto;
  /* height: 80vh; */
}

.left>div {
  height: 40000px;
  background: #e7e6de;
  padding: 5px;
}

.right {
  height: 300px;
  background: #e3e7e9;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">whatever relevant</div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="left">
      <div>lots of content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">another content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="header">whatever relevant 2</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It already does, even without 80vh

Comment: I does because I've added what I say in the EDIT part of the question, but I have to manually adjust the numbers, so the question is whether there is a more direct solution here

Comment: Why not use flexbox / column on the body and set a max-height of 100vh on that. Then you can force the grid to be flex:1. There's no reason why you can't mix & match layout methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest/neatest solution is flexbox. You can use it for static header/footer height or dynamic as well, just change the header/footer height set in px/vh respectively.

No need to use calc functions, and it's probably the best way to create dynamic grid as well.

```css
.site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
header, footer {
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body class="site">
  <header>Navigation</header>
  <main class="site-content">content goes here</main>
  <footer>Footer stuff</footer>
</body>
```